# How to create a scroller for handling page content going out of bound in Slidify?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, slidify

I am working with `Slidify` in `R` and I am facing this strange issue. If I am putting too much content which cannot be fit in a page or plotting something which overflows from the page then I can't see them in the `html`. Is there any way I can put a `scroller` on such pages which goes beyond the page height.

Comment: Scrolling would defeat the purpose of using a slide deck. I would suggest breaking up your content so that it fits.

Comment: @Ramnath I really appreciate your feedback. I could do that in "io2012" framework by changing the css property of a class(simply adding overflow: scroll). But I need to do that every time I make change in the presentation. Is there any way to do the same in R?

Comment: You can either directly add the CSS to your Rmd file, or drop it in a css file in the assets/css folder, which slidify will automatically pick up. If you end up adding scroll to every slide, I would question whether a slide deck is the best way for you to present your stuff. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ramnath, but for a dynamic presentation (without printing compliance), it could be interesting:

`<div style="width:1000px;overflow:scroll">
...
</div>`